# Проблема с восстановлением файла

Tags: jpeg, восстановление, recovery

Не могу восстановить JPEG файлы. Разрешение файлов 1х1 пиксель, т.е. 0 Мп. в то время как размер файлов варьируется от 850 кБ до 2.5 МБ, то есть информация об изображениях все еще как-то хранится.

Пробовал использовать для восстановления программы Hetman Partition Recovery, JPEG Recovery Pro 6, Stellar Phoenix JPEG Repair, но они не видят проблем с файлами и никак их не обрабатывают.

Какие вы знаете способы восстановления таких файлов? (программы, алогоритмы, онлайн-сервисы)

P.S. Ниже прикреплены непосредственно сами файлы.

[Файл1](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1etf_y0LjlCZkpDNUZqcUxQZGs)
[Файл2](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1etf_y0LjlCNjE0V0w5a2tjZHc)

Answer (score 1):

Файлы однозначно невосстановимы, поскольку забиты 0xFF. С исходными данными в них совпадает, в среднем, 1/256 часть.